# Program to list permutations of carbohydrate chains

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, permutation

I was tasked with creating a program that takes a hydrocarbon molecule, e.g. [Pentene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentene), C<sub>5</sub>H<sub>10</sub>, and outputs, preferably graphically, all of the possible permutations of its molecular chain. I'm not asking for it to be written for me (in fact, please don't), but could someone give me a good starting point? As for the language, I can use C#, Java or JavaScript and HTML (I'd prefer to make it using the latter, since it makes the graphical bit significantly easier).

The rules are as follows:

- Each Carbon atom must make 4 bonds, and each Hydrogen atom must make one.
- All of the chains *must* have the same amount of Carbon and Hydrogen atoms (so that they're all the same molecule).
- Two chains are considered "different" when one cannot be altered into the other one without making or breaking any bonds. For example, [all](http://www.gcsescience.com/2-methylbut-1-ene.gif) [these](http://images.flatworldknowledge.com/ball/ball-fig16_x171.jpg) [chains](http://www.gcsescience.com/2-methylbut-2-ene.gif) are different.
- Double bonds exist, and count as 2 bonds (this may sound like common sense, but I'm including it to remove any chance of a misunderstanding).
- Single bonds can be "twisted", i.e. the chain on the other side of the single bond can be flipped over. However, double bonds *cannot*. So, 2 chains with a "twisted" single bond are the same, but 2 chains with a "twisted" double bond are not.

Please ask me if anything above is in any way unclear.

EDIT: from what I've figured out so far, if there are no "rings" of Carbon atoms and no double bonds (a double bond is essentially a "ring" with only 2 atoms), the formula of the compound is C<sub>n</sub>H<sub>2n + 2</sub>. If the formula is C<sub>n</sub>H<sub>2n</sub>, as with Pentene, then there must be one *and only one* double bond *or* one ring (as mentioned, the two are the same).

EDIT 2: as per the last rule, the following 2 chains are the same:

```
      H               C-H
```

```
     /               /
…-C-C       and …-C-C
```

```
     \               \
      C-H             H
```

Since the single bond on the left can be twisted.

EDIT 3: In response to David, here is an example of 2 chains that *aren't* identical:

```
H H H
 \|/
H C H
 \|/
H C H
 \|/
H C H
 \|/
  C     H
  |    /
  C-C=C
  | |  \
  H H   C-H
        |\
        H H
```

and

```
H H H
 \|/
H C H
 \|/
H C H
 \|/
H C H   H H
 \|/    |/
  C     C-H
  |    /
  C-C=C
  | |  \
  H H   H
```

This is so because to make them identical, the C=C bond would have to be twisted, which isn't allowed, as it is a double bond.

Comment: I guess there aren't so many "permutations".. have you tried a brute force search approach?

Comment: I'm no chemist, but surely you mean hydrocarbon. Carbohydrates contain oxygen as well.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath 1. Indeed, for the smaller molecules there aren't many, but the numbers get very nasty as the amount of atoms gets bigger.
2. Even if an exhaustive search is possible, I still need help as to how to implement one.

Comment: @A.Webb Oh my god, did I really put that? Sorry, correcting. My bad.

Comment: can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve? It sounds more like a chemistry problem then programming challenge

Comment: @Pandrei What do you mean by example? I am trying to write a program to draw all of the chains (i.e. arrangements) of the atoms in a hydrocarbon molecule, akin to the images I linked to. If a molecule has 1000 different chains, then I need the program to calculate and draw all of those chains.

Comment: Does it need to work when the quantities dictate multiple rings?

Comment: one way you can do it is to have a atomChainMatrix which will tell you if there is a connection between atoms i and j. But that will not handle the pretty pictures :)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat if by that you mean when there is more than one ring/double bond, e.g. C (n) H (2n - 2), then preferably yes. However, if that makes the program much more complicated, then just one double bond or ring is fine.

Comment: If we have two chains C-C-C with attached Hs -- one where the order around the middle C is C, H, C, H; one where the order is C, C, H, H -- are they the same?

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean C-H-C-H as opposed to C-C-H-H, then both those chains are impossible (as an H can only make 1 bond), but you probably meant something else.

Comment: I mean, does the cyclic order of connections matter in determining isomorphism? The formula for the chains that I meant is C3H8.

Comment: Put another way, how many different C3H8 chains are there?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Just one. So probably not.

Comment: I think that I understand the ringless case and will be answering in a bit, but I don't seem to understand the prohibition against twisting a double bond. Could you give an example?

Comment: So the following 2 chains are the same (didn't work in comments, see my edit):
since the single bond at the beginning can be "twisted", along with everything to the right of it, and then the two would be identical (here, … represents the rest of the molecule).

However, if that single bond on the left were a *double* bond, then the two would *not* be the same, as a double bond *cannot* be twisted.

Comment: I drew in my answer what I believe to be your diagram with complete chains. Could you verify?

Comment: If we twist one single link in a carbon ring, does it act like a rubber band and twist correspondingly everywhere else on the ring? Is there some reference that I could peruse to get a better understanding?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat No, it does not. You can twist a segment separately from the rest of the molecule, *as long as* it is surrounded by *single* bonds.

Comment: @Bluefire You have 5 bonds on one of the `C`s in your double-bond examples.

Comment: @Bluefire Also, some structural graphs are not planar (example: [C6H6](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Biclique_K_3_3.svg)); you probably want to restrict your formulas to `C_n_H_2n+2` and `C_n_H_2n` to disallow such complicated cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithms for the ringless case are significantly easier, so I would start there. My suggested plan is as follows.

1. A *rooted* chain is a chain with one H (the *root*) distinguished from the others. Generate all inequivalent rooted chains.
2. For each generated rooted chain, retain it if and only if the root has been chosen "canonically" (more on this later). Now we have the inequivalent chains. (Steps 1 and 2 would be called something like "enumerating non-isomorphic unrooted 4-ary trees" in the algorithms literature.)
3. Draw the chains. As a first cut, use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), but there are many, many algorithms that embed trees "nicely" in the Euclidean plane. This is sort of a separate question.

#### Step 1

Instead of generating complete chains, generate incomplete chains with one open bond. We recover complete chains by bonding the root H.

An incomplete chain is an H, or a C with three bonded incomplete chains. This definition is recursive, and so is the natural generation strategy. Generate an incomplete chain with n Cs as follows.

- If n == 0, then output H.
- Otherwise, for every triple n1, n2, n3 >= 0 such that n1 + n2 + n3 == n, for every incomplete chain c1 with n1 Cs, for every incomplete chain c2 with n2 Cs, for every incomplete chain c3 with n3 Cs, if c1 <= c2 <= c3 (more on this later), then output the incomplete chain consisting of a C bonded with c1, c2, c3.

The condition c1 <= c2 <= c3 is because the order of bonds doesn't seem to matter here (please correct me if I'm wrong), and we don't want to generate multiple permutations. I haven't said what c <= c' means, though, so let's fix that.

If c == H, then c <= c'. Otherwise, if c' != H, then let c1 <= c2 <= c3 be the incomplete chains bonded with the open C of c and let c1' <= c2' <= c3' be the incomplete chains bonded with the open C of c'. I'm using <= before I've finished the definition, but that's OK because this definition is structurally inductive (i.e., recursive). If c1 <= c1' and ((not c1' <= c1) or (c2 <= c2' and ((not c2' <= c2) or c3 <= c3'))), then c <= c', otherwise not. In other words, we're comparing (c1, c2, c3) lexicographically to (c1', c2', c3'). Haskellers, this is what the derived Eq/Ord instances do for

```
data IncompleteChain = H | C IncompleteChain IncompleteChain IncompleteChain .
```

#### Step 2

We're going to use the order again. For each incomplete chain c, generate all c' obtained by completing c with a root H, then removing a different H and reforming the incomplete chain (remember to ensure sorted order of the bonded incomplete chains before comparing). If c is less than or equal to all of these c', then retain c, otherwise don't.

### One double bond

I'm leaving this section as a warmup. Let one of the doubly bonded carbons have incomplete singly bonded chains c1 and c2. Let the other have incomplete singly bonded chains c3 and c4. If I understand correctly, then there are four ways to generate equivalent chains (where one of the "ways" is to keep the existing chain): optionally swap (c1, c2) with (c3, c4), then optionally swap (c1, c3) with (c2, c4). To generate all n-carbon chains with a double bond, consider all n1, n2, n3, n4 >= 0 such that n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 == n, then all incomplete chains c1, c2, c3, c4 with n1, n2, n3, n4 carbons respectively. Output the chain if c1 <= c2 and (c1, c2) <= (min(c3, c4), max(c3, c4)).

### One ring

We can generate all n-carbon chains with one ring as follows. Iterate over how many carbons are in the ring (a number k between 2 and n). Iterate over partitions n1, n1', n2, n2', ..., nk, nk' >= 0 such that n1 + n1' + n2 + n2' + ... + nk + nk' = n - k. Iterate over all incomplete chains c1, c1', c2, c2', ..., ck, ck' with n1, n1', n2, n2', ..., nk, nk' carbons. Chains ci and ci' will be bonded to the ith carbon in the ring. To determine whether given c1, c1', c2, c2', ..., ck, ck' should be retained, generate isomorphic presentations as follows. Start with the list [c1, c1', c2, c2', ..., ck, ck']. Create a second list [ck, ck', ..., c2, c2', c1, c1']. Create a third list [c1', c1, c2', c2, ..., ck', ck] and a fourth [ck', ck, ..., c2', c2, c1', c1]. Create 4 (k - 1) more lists by permuting the carbons in a cycle (e.g., [c2, c2', c3, c3', ..., c1, c1']). If the original list is the lexicographic minimum of all of these lists, then retain it.

Comment: The last 2 chains *are* equivalent. Remember, a single bond *can* be twisted. However, if the bond to the *right* of the double bond was also a double bond, then the two would be different. See my edit.

Comment: Also, could you explain what you mean by "representative"?

Comment: @Bluefire Sorry, I'm mentally translating the language of group actions and missed a spot. I'm going to expand that section anyway now that I understand what's going on.

Comment: @Bluefire OK, I've expanded on the algorithm. Let me know if I seem to have understood the symmetries correctly. I hope that it's clear why I didn't tackle the multiring case -- fully generalized, we would need to handle arbitrary graph isomorphism.

Comment: I'm wondering, since a double bond is, essentially, the same as a ring, could the algorithm treat them both as one thing and have the same way of dealing with them? This isn't necessary, of course, I'm asking merely out of interest.

Comment: @Bluefire I'm handling them separately because my understanding is that, if we were to replace each bond of each double bond in your example with a CH2 group, then the chains would become identical.

Comment: @Bluefire Am I correct in assuming that if we have three carbons Ca Cb Cc in a ring with attached incomplete chains that completely distinguish them, then it doesn't matter whether the order in the ring is Ca Cb Cc or Cc Cb Ca?

Comment: It depends. If the incomplete chains are linked to the ring with double bonds, then if and only if twisting *the whole ring* will turn one chain into another are the two chains identical. If they are linked by single bonds, then doing that operation *or* twisting the incomplete chain around the single bond and generating another chain will make the 2 chains identical.

Comment: And I think that treating double bonds exactly as you would a ring would help emphasize the fact that they cannot be twisted without twisting the whole thing (you can't twist a ring, obviously).

Comment: @Bluefire I merged the two ring algorithms. The general idea behind these algorithms should be clear by now: check whether the generated object is less than or equal to all of its symmetric images.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, forall C atoms it holds that there must be at least one bound to another C molecule. For something like

```
C - H - C
```

is impossible. Therefore, I would start with the simpler task to make the C skeleton first.

This is relatively simple, as an C skeleton of n molecules can only be created from a skeleton with (n-1) molecules, and then there are so many possibilities to bind the last C.

Once you have the C skeleton, simply put H atoms on the not yet fully bound C atoms.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about your answer, but then realized that since a double bond can't be twisted, some skeletons can generate more than one "different" chain. Imagine C-C=C-C, where the 2nd C from the left has only one Hydrogen. Whether that Hydrogen is drawn above or below it *does* matter, as the two chains won't be the same.

But that idea *does* help, so thanks again.

Comment: When I understand you correctly, there are 2 ways to make a skeleton from 2 C: C-C and C=C. Don't know if it matters whether the 2nd one connects north, east, west or south of the old one. I any case, there are less items to permute if you leave out the H first, considering that a valid molecule **will** have one of the C skeletons in any case.

Comment: Indeed, as I said, considering it as a skeleton first *does* help. I think a good idea could be generating the skeletons and then populating them with Hydrogens as 2 distinct steps.